# Unable to import mongodb with full text search indexes

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to do a mongo restore with full text search indexes, but it returns the following error.

```
ERROR: Error creating index joyous.joyous_articles: 16730 err: "bad textIndexVersion: 2"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm doing this in AWS instance, ubuntu 14.04 and mongo version is 2.4.9
Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This error occurred due to the backward compatibility.Here I've tried to restore a dump from 2.6 version to 2.4.9.

2.6 version of mongo implements a stronger enforcement of the limit on index key.Referred from docs: [Compatibility Changes in Mongo 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6-compatibility/)

I've solved this by enabling full text search in mongodb.conf file by adding the following line.

```
setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
```

Restart the mongo services using

```
service mongodb restart
```

Then during restore i've skipped the indexes using following command

```
mongorestore --db joy_db --noIndexRestore dump/joy_db
```

--noIndexRestore will skip creating indexes during export.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. ;-)

Comment: Does using `--noIndexRestore` have any negative consequences? I've used the solution above, restoring v3.0.12 from a v3.0.7 dump. The restored version is giving me this error: `invalid operator '$setUnion'"` on some API endpoints, which didn't exist on the original db.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to restore database with mognodb 2.6 and the same error occured, but after reinstalling mongodb to 3.2 it started to work